# Assigned value in array changes after being assigned

Tags: c

In my code I need to build a function that's going to parse the content of a file and transform it into structures. The issue is that in that function in particular, on the first loop of the while, the **resultats** is going to have the right value in the array **titres**, but as soon as the new line is read (*fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)*), and the value of **line** changes, the value inside **resultats->titres** changes too. I'm relatively new to C and can't figure out why as I manage to have my functions working elsewhere(*see end of post*).
I have a feeling it's related to my limited understanding of pointers but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it !

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated !

**######## Code ########**

**structures:**
I didn't include it all but both structures have some getters and setters as well as a constructor and destructor

```
struct titre {
    char* tconst;
    char* primaryTitle;
    char* genres;
    char* titleType;
    int startYear;
};
typedef struct titre* t_titre;


struct resultats {
    int size;
    t_titre titres;
};
typedef struct resultats* t_resultats;
```

```
t_titre creer_titre(void) {
    t_titre titre;

    titre = (t_titre) malloc(sizeof(struct titre));
    memset(titre, 0, sizeof(*titre));

    if (titre) {
        titre->tconst = NULL;
        titre->primaryTitle = NULL;
        titre->genres = NULL;
        titre->titleType = NULL;
        titre->startYear = -1;
    }

    return titre;
}
 ...

void set_tconst(t_titre titre, char* tconst) {
    titre->tconst = tconst;
}
 ...
```

**Not working implementation:**

```
#include "imdb.h"
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 128

void parse_line(t_titre titre, char* line);
void filter_results(t_resultats results, t_critere filter);

t_resultats search_file(t_critere criteres, char* file_name) {
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    t_resultats resultats = creer_resultats();
    t_titre titre = creer_titre();

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open file %s\n", file_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file); //Skip header line 
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
        parse_line(titre, line);
        add_titre(resultats, titre);
    }

    free(titre);
    fclose(file);
    return NULL;
}

void parse_line(t_titre titre, char* line) {
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; //Remove trailling \n

    set_tconst(titre, strsep(&line, "\t"));
    set_titleType(titre, strsep(&line, "\t"));
    set_primaryTitle(titre, strsep(&line, "\t"));
    strsep(&line, "\t"); //Skip originalTitle
    strsep(&line, "\t"); //Skip isAdult
    set_startYear(titre, strtol(strsep(&line, "\t"), NULL, 10));
    strsep(&line, "\t"); //Skip endYear
    strsep(&line, "\t"); //Skip runtimeMinutes
    set_genres(titre, line); //Use remaining of line as it is the last value
}

void filter_results(t_resultats results, t_critere filter) {

}
```

**Working implementation:**

```
    t_resultats resultats = creer_resultats();
    t_titre t = creer_titre();

    set_tconst(t, "tt0000001");
    set_titleType(t, "short");
    set_primaryTitle(t, "It");
    set_startYear(t, 2015);
    set_genres(t, "Horror,Short");
    add_titre(resultats, t);

    set_tconst(t, "tt0000002");
    set_titleType(t, "short");
    set_primaryTitle(t, "ET");
    set_startYear(t, 2015);
    set_genres(t, "Horror,Short");
    add_titre(resultats, t);

    set_tconst(t, "tt0000003");
    set_titleType(t, "short");
    set_primaryTitle(t, "Interstellar");
    set_startYear(t, 2015);
    set_genres(t, "Sci-Fi,Short");
    add_titre(resultats, t);
```

Comment: There is a long time I don't look at C, but it seems that you are passing `titre` by value and not as a pointer. To pass as pointer you should `(t_titre *titre)` and when calling it you should call like `func( &titre)`. Take a look at this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm) here.

Comment: @JoaoSoares It is actually a pointer as I use the typedef do define a type equal to a pointer to my structure ! (I hate it but it's a requirement of the exercise). Thanks tho =)

Comment: @QuentinLevasseur, can you show the body of `set_tconst()` for example

Comment: @kuro I just Edited the post to add an example of getter and constructor

Comment: In `set_tconst()` you are just assigning the pointer in `titre->tconst = tconst`. So, for `set_tconst()` you are now pointing to the address of say `line[0]`. But in the next iteration of while loop you overwrite the previous content of `line`. So `titre->tconst` will also point to new value. To fix this, you have to allocate memory for `titre->tconst` and then copy the content `tconst` parameter in that.

Comment: Your second code works basically because the pointer you are passing to `set_tconst()` are different.

Comment: @kuro So something likle this ? ```void set_tconst(t_titre titre, char* tconst) {
    titre->tconst = (char*) malloc(sizeof(tconst));
    titre->tconst = tconst;
}```

Comment: @kuro I fugured they were different but in that case why would this not work ? ``` while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
        t_titre titre = creer_titre();
        parse_line(titre, line);
        add_titre(resultats, titre);
        free(titre);
    }```

Comment: not quite. you need `malloc` but the `sizeof(tconst)` won't do, because it represent sizeof a char* not the length of the string. Also the next assignment won't work either. You need something like `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`

Comment: @QuentinLevasseur, that will depend on `add_titre()`

Comment: @kuro here is **add_titre**: ```void add_titre(t_resultats resultats, t_titre titre) {
    resultats->size++;
    resultats->titres = realloc(resultats->titres, resultats->size * sizeof *resultats->titres);
    resultats->titres[resultats->size - 1] = *titre; 
}```

Comment: As for typedeffing pointers, you will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i don't have a choice with that sadly ! It's a requirement of the teacher

Comment: It happens. The crux of it is, typedeffed pointers can cause confusion as to the type, especially 1000 lines down in your code when a type pops up for the first time. That said, they have their place. The kernel code makes extensive use of them for list-pointers, etc. The general consensus is against typedeffing pointers, but with the caveat that there are places where there are accepted cases for using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple, I needed to change the setter methods in order to allocate memory then copy the value :

This :

```
void set_tconst(t_titre titre, char* tconst) {
    titre->tconst = (char*) malloc(sizeof(tconst));
    strcpy(titre->tconst, tconst);
}
```

Instead of this:

```
void set_tconst(t_titre titre, char* tconst) {
    titre->tconst = tconst;
}
```

Thanks everyone !